# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path:

Tags: package, certificate, bundle

I'm trying to install modules. I keep getting this error and am not sure how to fix it.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /path/to/cacert.pem

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To fix Mac error wrt  - ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: path\to\cacert.pem

Check the path using below command
pip3 config -v list

Will give below list here - global.cert was set to path  "path\to\cacert.pem"
For variant 'global', will try loading '/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/Users/vshanthe/.pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/Users/vshanthe/.config/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'site', will try loading '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/pip.conf'
global.cert='path\to\cacert.pem'

Now perform below command
pip3 config set global.cert ""

And check again : pip3 config -v list
For variant 'global', will try loading '/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/Users/vshanthe/.pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/Users/vshanthe/.config/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'site', will try loading '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/pip.conf'
global.cert=''

Now you can run
pip3 install certifi :  to install certs

Comment: didnt doo much, im on windows and still cannot find a way to fix this error, thank you got trying to help tho, i reinstalled python and still have this issue :(